# Visual Studio Code - "Error:spawn jdb ENOENT" trying to debug java app

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, jdb

I am trying to debug java application in Visual Studio Code and getting following error:
 `"Error:spawn jdb ENOENT".`

Vs Code is suggesting to update my launch.json which have following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasename}",
            "options": [
                "-classpath",
                "\"${fileDirname};.\""
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Java Console App",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasename}",
            "options": [
                "-classpath",
                "\"${fileDirname};.\""
            ],
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I am building using maven and have following  VSCode plugins installed https://github.com/DonJayamanne/javaVSCode.

Maven pow.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ams-sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>AMSSample</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>NumberGenerator</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/azure-storage-4.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.4</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/azure-core-0.9.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
     <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-media</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.4</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/azure-media-0.9.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

My assumption for now that VS Code is not able to find jdb.exe and i am trying to find where it should be configured.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is related to missing %PATH% pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`. Once system variable %PATH% has been modified to include `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin` VS Code launched java debugger.